# Integrating with a system that may or may not reply

Tags: java, apache-camel

One system I have to integrate with involves the following process:

1. Subscribing for a message about "foo" from MegaCorp.
   (As part of the subscription a callback method is provided which is used for
   notifications.)
2. Waiting for a notification via the callback method
3. Unsubscribing from messages about "foo".

However there are situations where there are are no notifications. What is the best way to handle this? I suspect there is an EIP for this, but I haven't managed to find one.

The approach we have in place involves using Apache Camel as follows:

**Route A**:

- Subscribe for messages about "foo".
  Request that notifications are sent to Route B.
- Send a AddSubscription to Route D.

**Route B** (Happy Path - received notification)

- If we receive a notification then do something useful with the data.
- Send a ReceivedNotification to Route D

**Route C** (Timer)

- This sends a String to Route D every X seconds to ensure we periodically unsubscribe from Subscriptions

**Route D** (Unsubscriber)

```
if (payload instanceOf AddSubscription)
    // Add to ListofSubscriptions with an expiry time
elseif (payload instanceOf ReceivedNotification)
    // Remove from ListOfSubscriptions
    // Unsubscribe
elseif (payload instanceOf String)
    // Remove expired subscriptions from ListOfSubscriptions
    // Unsubscribe
    // Note that we didn't receive a notification
```

Comment: I am a little confused. You subscribe, then expect one single message and unsubscribe again (="happy path")? I recommend the visitor-pattern to avoid if-elseif-elseif ...

Comment: Yes, that is how the API works. There are other use cases e.g. subscribing for updates continually where you could keep the subscription open for a long period of time. Thanks for the visitor pattern tip.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use the [Aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html) EIP for this. You could correlate an the initial subscription exchange with the notification. There's a completionTimeout option.